# Display value on Google Visualization Line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to show the values of the points of my line chart, similar to the column chart in its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) (Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3). My chart consists of a few data points at the moment, and while one can get the value when you hover on the point, we would like to make it "friendlier" to older or less technologically savvy users.

I can't find a way to do this. Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 0):

Line charts can do this exactly like the column charts.

Here is the [column chart example](http://jsfiddle.net/rsmrn20v/).
[image: ColumnChart Output]

Changing this

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
chart.draw(view, options);
```

to this

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
chart.draw(view, options);
```

in the example will yield [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1f8Luap8/).
[image: LineChart Output]

Comment: can you  do it as a dynamically data bind from data base and do this same  in line chart with displaying points also can you help me to how to do this